# Samba shares empty and not writeable when browsing OS X 10.8

Tags: centos, mac-osx, samba, file-server

When I mount a Samba share it works, but it doesn't show me any files, even though they exist on the server, I also cannot write files to the share either.

The server is CentOS 6.4, running Samba. Clients are 10.8.

1. I can mount a share from the server using: `smb://<ip>/<share name>`
2. I can: `telnet <ip> 445` successfully
3. user who mounts the share owns it in this case.

smb.conf:

```
#======================= Global Settings =====================================
[global]
interfaces = eth1 lo
bind interfaces only = yes
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = share
map to guest = bad user
#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[MyShare]
user="<user>"
force user = <user>
comment = MyShare Files
path = /drobo/users/<user>
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
public = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
```

What changes need to be made so that the files that already exist can be seen as well as allowing write permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Are you giving access to multiple users that have home directories.

You might add

[homes]

browsable = no 
    writable = yes

You will need to restart the samba server